# How to make fill color consistent when plotting subsets of a dataframe with ggvis

Tags: r, colors, shiny, fill, ggvis

I am trying to make the colors in a ggvis plot remain consistent whenever the data is re-plotted based on the factors (unfortunately I apparently lack enough reputation to include pictures to show you).

I could only find one other post about this [controlling-color-of-factor-group-in-ggvis-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454976/controlling-color-of-factor-group-in-ggvis-r) but none of his solutions or workarounds work in my situation.

my data looks like this:

```
         month year     date entity_name prefix module module_entry_key entity_table_name count
    0  January 2011 2011.000   AbLibrary    LIB   Base               BS        AB_LIBRARY     0
    1 February 2011 2011.083   AbLibrary    LIB   Base               BS        AB_LIBRARY     0
    2    March 2011 2011.167   AbLibrary    LIB   Base               BS        AB_LIBRARY     0
    3    April 2011 2011.250   AbLibrary    LIB   Base               BS        AB_LIBRARY     0
    4      May 2011 2011.333   AbLibrary    LIB   Base               BS        AB_LIBRARY     0
    5     June 2011 2011.417   AbLibrary    LIB   Base               BS        AB_LIBRARY     0
 3000  January 2011 2011.000      Vector    VEC   Base               BS            VECTOR     0
 3001 February 2011 2011.083      Vector    VEC   Base               BS            VECTOR     0
 3002    March 2011 2011.167      Vector    VEC   Base               BS            VECTOR     0
 3003    April 2011 2011.250      Vector    VEC   Base               BS            VECTOR   569
 3004      May 2011 2011.333      Vector    VEC   Base               BS            VECTOR   664
 3005     June 2011 2011.417      Vector    VEC   Base               BS            VECTOR   775
```

I'm using a shiny app to display the page in a browser, and the relevant code is:

```
 # render the plot, filtering for entities within the module minus any entities selected from the exclude panel
  plot <- reactive({ 
    if (input$filter==1){
      data <- dplyr::filter(.data=melted, module_entry_key %in% input$module)
    }
    else{
      data <- dplyr::filter(.data=melted, entity_name == input$entity) 
    }
    data <- dplyr::filter(.data=data, !entity_name %in% input$excluded)
    data$entity_name <- factor(data$entity_name)
    data %>%
      ggvis(x = ~date, y = ~count, fill = ~entity_name, key := ~id, fillOpacity := 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 0.9) %>%
      add_legend("fill", title="Entities") %>%
      layer_points() %>% 
      add_tooltip(tooltipText, "hover") %>% 
      add_axis("y", title = "Count", title_offset = 50) %>% 
      add_axis("x", title="Date", title_offset=50, subdivide=6, tick_size_minor=3, format=parseDate(~year, ~month))

  })
```

the filter is creating the subset of "melted" as "data" based on the filters in the UI (see picture)

since as far as I can tell there is no way to associate a fill color to a factor (the entity name) explicitly and the color is chosen by alphabetical order of the factors, whenever I make a new subset of data the colors are changed.

Is there any way to work around this?

(full shiny code)

server.R

```r
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  modules_list <- as.character(c("Base" = "BS",
                                 "Screening" = "SC",
                                 "Protein Engineering" = "EN",
                                 "Protein Production" = "PP",
                                 "CD",
                                 "PT",
                                 "PD"))


  #melted <- read.table(file="~/dataOut.txt", sep="\t", strip.white=TRUE, row.names=1, header=TRUE);


  modules <- as.character(as.vector(unique(melted$module_entry_key)))
  modules <- modules[modules != "null"]
  entities <- as.character(as.vector(unique(melted$entity_name)))
  entities <- entities[entities != "null"]

  for (i in entities){
    melted <- rbind(melted, data.frame(month=NA, year=NA, date=NA, entity_name=i, prefix=NA, module=NA, module_entry_key=NA, entity_table_name=NA, count=NA))
  }
  melted$id <- 1:nrow(melted)

  #create ui checkbox for modules in the data
  output$module_list <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "module",
                       label = "Module",
                       choices = modules,
                       selected = "BS")
  })

  #create the ui list for entities 
  output$entity_list <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "entity",
      label = "Entity",
      choices = entities,
      selected = "Vector"
    )
  })

  #ex <- entities

  #create the checkboxGroupInput with entities to 'exclude'
  output$exclusion_entities <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "excluded", label = "Exclude", 
                       choices = entities)
  })

  #update the excluded entities list with entities within a particular module
  observe({
    if (input$filter==1)
      ex1 <- as.character(as.vector(unique(dplyr::filter(.data=melted, module_entry_key %in% input$module)$entity_name)))
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "excluded", "Exclude", choices=ex1, selected = input$excluded )       
  })


  # render the plot, filtering for entities within the module minus any entities selected from the exclude panel
  plot <- reactive({ 
    if (input$filter==1){
      data <- dplyr::filter(.data=melted, module_entry_key %in% input$module)
    }
    else{
      data <- dplyr::filter(.data=melted, entity_name == input$entity) 
    }
    data <- dplyr::filter(.data=data, !entity_name %in% input$excluded)
    data$entity_name <- factor(data$entity_name)
    data %>%
      ggvis(x = ~date, y = ~count, fill = ~entity_name, key := ~id, fillOpacity := 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 0.9) %>%
      add_legend("fill", title="Entities") %>%
      layer_points() %>% 
      add_tooltip(tooltipText, "hover") %>% 
      add_axis("y", title = "Count", title_offset = 50) %>% 
      add_axis("x", title="Date", title_offset=50, subdivide=6, tick_size_minor=3, format=parseDate(~year, ~month))

  })

  #function to add color and mouse-over effect to layer_points() (unused in this code)
  points <- reactive({
    layer_points(fillOpacity := 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1, fill.hover := "red")
  })

  #d3 date format for formatting x-axis text 
  parseDate <- function(year, month){
    paste("d3.time.format(\"%Y\").parse(", year, ")", sep="")
  }

  #function for what to display in mouse-hover tooltip
  tooltipText <- function(x) {
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    row <- melted[melted$id == x$id, ]
    paste(row$entity_name, ": ", row$count, sep="")
  }

  #bind the plot to the UI
  plot %>% #layer_points(fill = ~factor(entity_name)) %>% 
    bind_shiny("ggvis")

  #select all button for modules
  observe({
    if (input$selectall ==0){
      return(NULL)
    }  
    else if ((input$selectall%%2)==0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "module", "Module", choices = modules)
    }
    else{
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "module", "Module", choices=modules, selected=modules)
    }
  })
  #select all button for excluded entities
  observe({
    list <- as.character(as.vector(unique(dplyr::filter(.data=melted, module_entry_key %in% input$module)$entity_name)))
    if (input$exclude_all ==0){
      return(NULL)
    }  
    else if ((input$exclude_all%%2)==0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "excluded", "Exclude", choices=list )     
    }
    else{
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "excluded", "Exclude", choices=list, selected=list ) 
    }
  })

  #---general output / debugging stuff ----#
  output$table <- renderTable({dataInput()})

  output$entity_selected = renderPrint({
    list <- as.character(as.vector(unique(dplyr::filter(.data=melted, module_entry_key %in% input$module)$entity_name)))
    entities[!entities %in% input$excluded & entities %in% list]
  })

  output$filter_value = renderPrint({input$filter})
  output$modules = renderPrint({input$module})
  output$link = renderPrint(input$selectall%%2)
  #----------------------------------------#

})
```

ui.R

```r
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("DB Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width=3,
      radioButtons(inputId="filter",
                   label="Filter",
                   choices = list("By Module" = 1, "By Entity" = 2), 
                   selected = 1),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.filter == 1",
                       uiOutput("module_list"),
                       actionButton("selectall", "Select All"),
                       uiOutput("exclusion_entities"),
                       actionButton("exclude_all", "Select All")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.filter == 2",              
                       uiOutput("entity_list")
      )      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Cumulative Entity Counts over Time (years)", align="center"),
      #verbatimTextOutput("value"),
      #verbatimTextOutput("filter_value"),
      #verbatimTextOutput("modules"),
      #tableOutput("table"),
      ggvisOutput("ggvis"),
      verbatimTextOutput("link"),
      verbatimTextOutput("entity_selected")
     #textOutput("entities_plot")
    )
  )
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the best way to do it. Try something like this:

```
df[which(df$entity_name == "AbLibrary"),]$color <- "FF0000"
df[which(df$entity_name == "Vector"),]$color <- "#FFB90F"
```

For each one in your data frame. Set your fill then to color each time. The only problem is trying to make a legend. (I have been trying to figure that out, so if I find it I will edit this post.

Comment: have you found a way to make the legend?