# R - How to Plot Multiple Density Plots With ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis, density-plot

How would one go about plotting multiple density plots on the same set of axes? I understand how to plot multiple line graphs and scatter plots together, however the matter of having the density plots share a common x-axis is tripping me up. My data is currently set up as such:

```
name  x1   x2   x3
a     123  123  123
b     123  123  123
c     123  123  123
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Here are some details I was missing which may help make my question clearer.

I have a data frame `attr_gains` which looks like the example above, and whose variable names are `Str`, `Agi`, and `Int`. So far, I have been able to get a density plot of the `Str` variable alone with this code:

```
  attr_gains %>%
  ggvis(x=~Str)%>%
  layer_densities(fill :="red", stroke := "red")
```

What I would like to do is overlay two more density plots, one for `Agi` and `Int` each, so that I have three density plots on the same set of axes.

Comment: There are some examples here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Thank you for the link. It appears as though these methods apply to ggplot2, whereas I am concerned with ggvis.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck? Please supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. You can have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: I will edit the OP with some clarification; thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the documentation:

```
PlantGrowth %>% 
  ggvis(~weight, fill = ~group) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  layer_densities()
```

[Link](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/ggvis/man/layer_densities.html)

Your Case:

```
set.seed(1000)
library('ggvis')
library('reshape2')

#############################################

df = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 5))
colnames(df) <- c('names', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'colors')

df['names'] <- c('a','b','c')    
df['x1'] <- runif(3, 100.0, 150.0)
df['x2'] <- runif(3, 100.0, 150.0)
df['x3'] <- runif(3, 100.0, 150.0)
df['colors'] <- c("blue","orange","green")

df <- melt(df)

#############################################

df %>% 
  ggvis( ~value, fill = ~colors ) %>% 
  group_by(names) %>%
  layer_densities()
```

Please see [this SE page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454976/controlling-color-of-factor-group-in-ggvis-r) for information on controlling ggvis color(s).

---

Looks like this:

[image: Density Plot]

Comment: Thank you! I had not thought to use 'reshape2', I was attempting to do this with just ggvis. I tried it with reshape2 though and it worked, I appreciate your help. As I had a hard time finding information about stacking multiple density plots with ggvis, do you know how I would go about specifying the colors of each density plot? Or do you know of a resource I could use to figure it out?