# ggvis color line graphs and corresponding legend

Tags: r, plot, legend, ggvis

I am plotting a ggvis graph with different colors and linetype by setting stroke and strokeDash parameters. 
The colors are not showing what I want, for ex: I need "red", "blue" and "green" colors where as the colors shown are " blue", "orange" and "green".(code example and screenshot are below).

I also need to add legend based on the color and linetype. I am unable to add the legend combining both "color type"(stroke) and "line type"(strokeDash).

Below is a sample code I am working.

```
mydf <- data.frame(xval = c(1:5),USA = c(11:15), Canada = c(21:25), UK = c(31:35))

mydf2 <- tidyr::gather(mydf, 'var', 'val', -xval)

mydf2$mycol <- c(rep("Red",5), rep("Blue",5), rep("Green",5))
mydf2$mydash <- c(rep(5,5), rep(-1,5), rep(10,5))

myggv2 <- mydf2 %>% ggvis(x = ~xval, y = ~val, stroke = ~mycol,      
strokeDash := ~mydash) %>% layer_points(size := 100) %>%
add_tooltip(function(d) { paste0("x:", d$xval, "<br>", "y:", d$val) }, "hover") %>% group_by(var) %>% 
layer_paths() %>% add_axis("x", title = "qtrs") %>% 
  add_axis("y", title = "MEV")%>% hide_legend("stroke")
myggv2
```

Here is the screenshot of the graph.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5asG.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: For the main color question you are just missing `:=` to set colors instead of map colors.  See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454976/controlling-color-of-factor-group-in-ggvis-r).  If I wanted a legend, though, I might map `var` to stroke and then change the colors using `scale_nominal`.  There is currently no `strokeDash` legend available.  See [here](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/187).

Comment: Thanks @aosmith for your suggestion. could you please write the code for the same. I am still new to ggvis plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors in your plot and legend for discrete variables using `scale_nominal`.

In this approach, you map the variable you want in the legend within the plotting code and then change away from the default colors using your chosen colors.  I'm using `var` for the `stroke` variable in this example.

```
mydf2 %>%
    ggvis(x = ~xval, y = ~val, stroke = ~var,      
          strokeDash := ~mydash) %>% 
    layer_points(size := 100) %>%
    add_tooltip(function(d) { paste0("x:", d$xval, "<br>", "y:", d$val) }, "hover") %>% 
    group_by(var) %>% 
    layer_paths() %>% 
    add_axis("x", title = "qtrs") %>% 
    add_axis("y", title = "MEV") %>%
    scale_nominal("stroke", label = "Country", range = unique(mydf2$mycol))
```

[image]

Note that at this time ggvis does not support a `strokeDash` legend. See [this open github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/187).